# C# void method how to pass any kind of List<something> in the argument

Tags: c#, datagridview

So I trying to create a method, in a static class, in order to update the latest data in a datagridView from any kind list. here the method:

```
  public static void FillDataGridView(List<object> pList, DataGridView pdgv)
    {
        int i = 0;
        pdgv.Rows.Clear();

        //obtain the first item in the list
        var item = pList.FirstOrDefault();
        if(item is SST_StakeholderStaff)
        {
            List<SST_StakeholderStaff> list = pList.Cast<SST_StakeholderStaff>().ToList();

            if (list.Count()>0)
            {
                pdgv.Rows.Add(list.Count());

                foreach (SST_StakeholderStaff staff in list)
                {
                    pdgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = staff.SST_ID;
                    pdgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = staff.SST_Last_Name;
                    pdgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = staff.SST_First_Name;
                    pdgv.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = staff.SST_Postion;
                    pdgv.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = staff.SST_Email;
                    i++;

                }
            }
        }
        else if(item is RIP_Recent_Interaction_Participants)
        {
            List<RIP_Recent_Interaction_Participants> list = pList.Cast<RIP_Recent_Interaction_Participants>().ToList();


                if (list.Count() > 0)
                {
                    pdgv.Rows.Add(list.Count());
                    foreach(RIP_Recent_Interaction_Participants participant in list)
                    {
                        pdgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = participant.RIP_ID;
                        pdgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = participant.RIP_Name_Participant;
                        i++;
                    }

                }

        }
        else if(item is RIMP_Recent_Interaction_Materials_Prepared)
        {
            List<RIMP_Recent_Interaction_Materials_Prepared> list = pList.Cast<RIMP_Recent_Interaction_Materials_Prepared>().ToList();
            if(list.Count()> 0)
            {
                pdgv.Rows.Add(list.Count());
                foreach(RIMP_Recent_Interaction_Materials_Prepared Material in list)
                {
                   pdgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = Material.RIMP_ID;
                   pdgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = Material.RIMP_Serial_Number;
                   pdgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = Material.RIMP_Name_Material;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically my code will check what kind of object (or class) does this plist has.after that, he will refresh the datagridview selected.
Howerver when I call this method into my main code, I am always getting an error saying that I can't convert a List into a List.

```
 GUI.FillDataGridView(List_SST.Where(x => x.SST_ST_ID == int.Parse(txtID.Text)), dgvStaff);
```

[image]

Please note that in my program I have three different datagridview and classes

Comment: Please post the exact error

Comment: That is not the error you are getting, read it again carefully and you should see what you need to do. (Hint: `List<>` is not the same as `IEnumerable<>`)

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]. Most of the code you've posted is fairly irrelevant. It sounds like you *probably* just need a `ToList<object>()` call: `List_SST.Where(x => x.SST_ST_ID == int.Parse(txtID.Text)).ToList<object>()` but you haven't really shown us enough to be sure. I'd also strongly advise you to start following .NE Tnaming conventions.

Comment: The error message tells you the line # and column # where the error occurs. On which line are you getting the error? (Please do not let us guess!). And, if the first item in the list is of the required type then obviously, the list count is > 0! The check `if(list.Count()> 0)` is superfluous.

Comment: while I am calling this method (from a static class) it just says that I can convert any type of list into a list<object>. I was just wondering if there is any other way to pass any type of list<something> in the argument.

Comment: Like I said already, *read the error closely*. It doesn't say you can't convert a List to a List.

Comment: here the thing my List_SST =  List<SST_StakeholderStaff> . it's still a list. I don't know why i'ts say that List_SST is a IEnumerable<>

Comment: The compiler *isn't* the one that's wrong here. `List_SST.Where(x => x.SST_ST_ID == int.Parse(txtID.Text))` doesn't return a `List`.

Comment: The problem is not List_SST - it is the call to Where method that is returning the IEnumerable<>

Comment: `List_SST.Where(x=> x.SST_ST_ID==...)` allow me to filter all the Staff who are in a certain company `(equals to txtID.Text)` the txtID id the ID of the Company. but still, by using the Where, will it not return a list at the end ?

Comment: No, `Where()` returns an `IEnumerable<>` which is why you need to do `list.Where(...).ToList()`. Seriously, this has been said several times in this thread, the compiler tells you the same and if you took a look at the `Where()` method you would see it there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment, I deduce that the error is not happening in the code shown, but when calling it. The problem is that a `List<SomeType>` is not assignment compatible to a `List<object>`. This would allow you to insert an object of any kind into the `List<object>` which is in reality a `List<SomeType>` and allows only items of type `SomeType` (and derived types) to be inserted.

Change the method signature to

```
public static void FillDataGridView(IEnumerable pList, DataGridView pdgv)
```

Then get the first item with

```
object item = pList.Cast<object>().FirstOrDefault();
```